# Oracle: invalid identifier in subselect

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

I am trying to use a subselect to get the last row from an associated table but it seems the subselect doesn't know about one of the tables involved that is in the outer query, the error is at kd.KPI_DEF_ID, invalid identifier. Replacing this with a number makes the query valid.

```
SELECT bp.bp_id,
     kd.kpi_def_id,
     kd.kpi_name,
     ks.kpi_status_now,
     kd.threshold_min_val,
     kd.threshold_max_val,
     kd.threshold_min_alert,
     kd.threshold_max_alert,
     e.event_id,
     e.event_name,
     (SELECT *
      FROM   (SELECT l.log_desc
            FROM   rator_monitoring.alert_logs l
            WHERE  l.kpi_def_id = kd.kpi_def_id
            ORDER  BY TIMESTAMP DESC)
      WHERE  rownum = 1) log_desc
FROM   business_process bp
JOIN   kpi_definition kd
ON     (kd.bp_id = bp.bp_id)
JOIN   rator_monitoring.kpi_status ks
ON     (ks.kpi_def_id = kd.kpi_def_id)
JOIN   event e
ON     (e.event_id = kd.event_id)
WHERE  kd.kpi_active_current = 'Y';
```

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You have a sub-subquery that references tables from the outermost query. Alas, Oracle doesn't allow referencing tables more than one level deep. (Which sucks!) What Oracle version are you using? In Oracle 11 and above, the best way to fix this is with a WITH clause.

Comment: Bad news is you can't reference more than 1 level up.  (this is by design) So the reference to KD is too far removed.   we'd have to restructure the query. either by CTE or movign the select to a join somehow...

Answer (score 3):

You need to convert the log_desc scalar subquery so that the correlated join is done in the top level. For example, something like:

```
SELECT ...
       (SELECT max(l.log_desc) keep (dense_rank first order by l.timestamp desc)
        FROM   rator_monitoring.alert_logs l
        WHERE  l.kpi_def_id = kd.kpi_def_id) log_desc
FROM   ...
```

N.B. untested.

Comment: Works, but is a tad slow. I guess Ill admit defeat and split it into two queries,,

Answer (score 1):

UNTESTED: Restructured as a join using inline views; not sure about performance though...

```
SELECT bp.bp_id,
     kd.kpi_def_id,
     kd.kpi_name,
     ks.kpi_status_now,
     kd.threshold_min_val,
     kd.threshold_max_val,
     kd.threshold_min_alert,
     kd.threshold_max_alert,
     e.event_id,
     e.event_name,
     l.log_desc
FROM   business_process bp
JOIN   kpi_definition kd
  ON   kd.bp_id = bp.bp_id
JOIN   rator_monitoring.kpi_status ks
  ON   ks.kpi_def_id = kd.kpi_def_id
JOIN   event e
  ON   e.event_id = kd.event_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT log_Desc
        FROM rator_monitoring.alert_logs 
        INNER JOIN (SELECT max(timestamp) mts, kpi_def_ID 
                    FROM  rator_monitoring.alert_logs 
                    GROUP BY kpi_def_ID) Z
          ON Z.mts = l.timestamp
         AND Z.kpi_def_ID = l.kpi_def_ID) l
  ON l.kpi_def_id = kd.kpi_def_id
WHERE  kd.kpi_active_current = 'Y';
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be a left outer join from the alert_logs table back to the kpi_definition table?

Comment: Ah yes. it should as there may not be a log Desc for each record. and we wouldn't want to eliminate data

Comment: Note that if `(kp_def_id,timestamp)` tuple is not guaranteed to be unique, this has potential for inline view `l` to have multiple rows with the same value of `kpi_def_id`.  To insure at `l` returns at most one row per `kp_def_id`, we'd need a `GROUP BY kp_def_id` and an aggregate around `log_desc`... `MIN(log_desc)` or `MAX(log_desc)`

Comment: Good point to @spencer7593 I did make that assumption. timestamp in most of what I work with usually means it's unique, but that's not certainly not a guarantee.

Comment: I'd like this, but I get an error `ORA-00904: "L"."KPI_DEF_ID": invalid identifier` upon execution.